# Couldn't find Wiki with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to load the `show` view, displaying a "wiki" that was created, I get the error message `Couldn't find Wiki with 'id'=`

It specifically points to the second line in the Controller:

```
def show
  @wiki = Wiki.find(params[:id]) ## shows the error in this line
end
def index
  @wikis = Wiki.all
end
```

The following is my view:

```
<h1><%= @wiki.title %></h1>
<h3><%= @wiki.body %></h3>
```

And the following are my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'wikis/index'
  get 'wikis/show'
  get 'wikis/new'
  get 'wikis/edit'
  get 'wikis/create'
  devise_for :users
  get 'welcome/index'
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

Why am I getting this error message, and how can I get the view to load?

Thank you.

Comment: What url you try to get? What are your routes? What's the server logs?

Comment: Is there any value pass in params see your rails console

Comment: Just added the routes to the main question. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @pitabasprathal, yes, when I check the rails console they have an id, title, and body

Comment: Why don't you use `resources :wikis` instead of defining each route separately? And BTW `create` action available with `get`? It's bad.

Comment: Going back to your original problem, I also asked you for the url you try to get.

Comment: Post your params value

Comment: I'm using this in the index view: 
'<%= link_to wiki.title, wikis_show_path %>' ; that does not give me an error message when the show action in the controller is blank.

Answer (score 1):

There is no :id param unless you pass it in explicity according to how your routes are set up. That is, you'd have to go to `/wikis?id=<some id>`, which is probably not what you want. Consider a more standard resourceful route setup:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :wikis
  devise_for :users
  get 'welcome/index'
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

which lets you go to `/wikis/<id>` (that is, `wiki_path(@wiki)` in the controller) for the show route, and defines the `index`, `create`, etc routes for you correctly. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: I changed my routes to your example above, but I still receive the same error message.

Comment: @sergio change the link accordingly. BTW how did you expect it to work since you didn't pass your `wiki` id to the link anywhere?

Comment: did you change the `wiki_show_path` to `wiki_path(@wiki)`? The url helper needs to know which wiki object to link to.

Comment: So I changed the routes as shown above, but when I do that now the index view doesn't show, it shows the "show" view.

Comment: Is that via `wikis_path`? That should evaluate to "/wikis", which should hit the index action.

Comment: what about "localhost:3000/wikis"? I think what you types is trying to find a wiki with id="index", which it shouldn't be able to find.

Comment: I'd highly recommend setting aside some time to go through the Rails routing guide at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html . Also, type `rake routes` in your console, it will display a list of the routes: controller actions & corresponding urls that hit those routes.

Comment: "localhost:3000/wikis" sent me to the index page. Thank you. I will read the guide.

Answer (score 1):

You have this error because you don't pass `wiki`'s id into your show link, so the simplest solution is providing an id:

```
<%= link_to wiki.title, wikis_show_path(id: wiki) %>
```

But to be honest, your code looks very ugly with these custom routes to `wikis` controller which can be replaced by putting simply:

```
resources :wikis
```

in your routes.rb. This way, link to single `wiki` show page is also simpler:

```
<%= link_to wiki.title, wiki %>
```

You may want to read [Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your `params[:id]` is most likely `nil` unless you pass it like `/wikis/show?id=123`, because route `get 'wikis/show'` does not have any params.

Most common approach is to have `resources :wikis` and routes like `/wikis/123`

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your routes

`resources :wikis`

and remove this code:

`get 'wikis/index'
  get 'wikis/show'
  get 'wikis/new'
  get 'wikis/edit'
  get 'wikis/create'`

Now you can write in url: websitename.com/wikis to index, websitename.com/wikis/id, websitename.com/wikis/id/edit to edit... and get your id param...

Read more about resources in this link: [Resources Link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)